# Start services manually when doing a spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

So I have a test class annotated with @SpringBootTest

```
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class IntegrationTests {}
```

This code automatically starts two of classes in my application annotated with @service.
In my integration test I’m testing the spring scheduler to works as expected and the tests passes.

Now I want to write another test that only test one of the two services annotated with @service. The second service I want to enable and disable myself. This is because one of two services uses the springboot @scheduled annotation, which results in unpredictable logic.

So is there a way I can start a @SpringBootTest with the possibility to choose the services I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-enabled-conditionally)

Comment: yes Autowire the requied one and mock the unwanted one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the test classes in @SpringBootTest? like so:
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourTestClass.class)